# ASP.NET how can I put 2 dbContext.SaveChanges() into a single transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Job table and I'll use the newly inserted Job.Id to insert another table called CompanyJobs

To insert a job I do

```
var job = new Job{Name = "Name"}
dbContext.Jobs.Add(job);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then with the newly inserted Job I use it's ID to insert CompanyJobs

```
var companyJobs = new CompanyJob{Name="Name",JobId = Job.Id};
dbContext.CompanyJobs.Add(companyJobs);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Let's say there is a possibility of error in inserting CompanyJobs

How can I enclose the 2 dbContext.SaveChanges() in one transaction?

Comment: dbContext.Database.StartTransaction()

Comment: But why do you want to call SaveChanges after each change? Just put everything together and call SaveChanges at the end

Comment: You are using Entity Framework 6, correct?

Comment: sorry I got mixed in my head, I've updated the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you do not need two `SaveChanges`, you can do both in one call:

```
var category = dbContext.Categories.Find(2);
var job = new Job{Name = "Name"}
job.Categories.Add(category);
dbContext.Jobs.Add(job);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

If you really need two transactions, then according to [this docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx) you should:

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
        var job = new Job{Name = "Name"}
        dbContext.Jobs.Add(job);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        var category = dbContext.Categories.Find(2);
        job.Categories.Add(category);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        dbContextTransaction.Commit(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another options is to use TransactionScope:

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) 
{ 
    var job = new Job{Name = "Name"}
    dbContext.Jobs.Add(job);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    var category = dbContext.Categories.Find(2);
    job.Categories.Add(category);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    transactionScope.Complete(); 
}
```

If `Complete` has not been called when exiting the `using` block (ie: an exception has occurred), the transaction is rolled back.

If you're using async methods, you need to pass the `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` parameter to the Transactionscope's constructor.

Comment: thanks for this additional info since I'll be using the dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();